# Finding areas in 2d array with python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have the following 2d array:

```
[
[1,1,1,2,2],
[1,1,2,3,2],
[2,2,2,3,1],
[2,1,0,3,2],
[2,0,3,3,0]]
```

As can be seen, there are zones in the 2d array with the same values, if the amount of cells in a zone is 5 or higher, the values become zero, resulting in the following array:

```
[
[0,0,0,2,2],
[0,0,0,0,2],
[0,0,0,0,1],
[0,1,0,0,2],
[0,0,0,0,0]]
```

My question is if there is any algorithm that can solve this problem? I have tried to look up solutions on stackoverflow or google, but I was not able to find any or come up with any solution by myself.

Comment: Why aren't the 3 cells of "2" in the top-right corner considered a zone with sum over 5?

Comment: Sorry, I meant not the sum of the numbers in the zone, I meant the total amount of cells in the zone

Comment: What defines a zone?

Comment: which and all the elements you want to make 0 ? in your sample o/p i don't get any logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Flood-Fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). For each cell that you haven't visited yet, do a DFS or BFS to all the adjacent cells unless those have a different value. Then, check how many cells you visited in that way and set those to `0` if there are at least `5`.

```
seen = set()
for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr[i])):
        if (i,j) not in seen:
            # start flood-fill from that position
            same = [(i,j)]
            pos = 0
            while pos < len(same):
                x, y = same[pos]
                for x2, y2 in ((x+1,y), (x-1,y), (x,y+1), (x,y-1)):
                    if 0 <= x2 < len(arr) and  0 <= y2 < len(arr[x2]) and \
                            (x2,y2) not in seen and arr[x2][y2] == arr[i][j]:
                        same.append((x2,y2))
                        seen.add((x2,y2))
                pos += 1
            # check size of zone and set to zero
            if len(same) >= 5:
                for i2, j2 in same:
                    arr[i2][j2] = 0
```

With `arr` being your 2D-array, this gives the result as

```
[[0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my DFS-like approach to this problem (Complexity O(rows * columns)):

```
# given array
ayyyarray = [
[1,1,1,2,2],
[1,1,2,3,2],
[2,2,2,3,1],
[2,1,0,3,2],
[2,0,3,3,0]]

# function that mark "color" on cell and call take_a_tour for all neighbours with the same number
def take_a_tour(ayyyarray, visited, y, x, act_group_number, group_members_cnt):
    visited[y][x] = act_group_number
    if act_group_number in group_members_cnt:
        group_members_cnt[act_group_number] += 1
    else: 
        group_members_cnt[act_group_number] = 1

    if (x + 1 < len(ayyyarray[y])) and (visited[y][x + 1] == 0) and (ayyyarray[y][x + 1] == ayyyarray[y][x]):
        take_a_tour(ayyyarray, visited, y, x + 1, act_group_number, group_members_cnt)
    if (y + 1 < len(ayyyarray)) and (visited[y + 1][x] == 0) and (ayyyarray[y + 1][x] == ayyyarray[y][x]):
        take_a_tour(ayyyarray, visited, y + 1, x, act_group_number, group_members_cnt)
    if (x - 1 >= 0) and (visited[y][x - 1] == 0) and (ayyyarray[y][x - 1] == ayyyarray[y][x]):
        take_a_tour(ayyyarray, visited, y, x - 1, act_group_number, group_members_cnt)
    if (y - 1 >= 0) and (visited[y - 1][x] == 0 ) and (ayyyarray[y - 1][x] == ayyyarray[y][x]):
        take_a_tour(ayyyarray, visited, y - 1, x, act_group_number, group_members_cnt)

# 0 if not painted, color code(group_number) if already painted
visited = [[0 for _ in range(len(ayyyarray[x]))] for x in range(len(ayyyarray))]
# actual color we are using to paint same cells
act_group_number = 1
# dictionary to store pairs [color : number_of_cells_using_this_color]
group_members_cnt = {}

# for every cell i call take_a_tour.
for y in range(len(ayyyarray)):
    for x in range(len(ayyyarray[y])):
        if not visited[y][x]:
            take_a_tour(ayyyarray, visited, y, x, act_group_number, group_members_cnt)
            act_group_number += 1

# setting 0 for every cell that are painted with color used in >= 5 cells.
for y in range(len(ayyyarray)):
    for x in range(len(ayyyarray[y])):
        if group_members_cnt[visited[y][x]] >= 5:
            ayyyarray[y][x] = 0

# print result
for y in ayyyarray:
    print(y)
```